# how to move an edge along it's normal but snap in world space?

Tags: snapping

Here's my example.   I have a vertical plane and above it a plane angled at 30 degrees.  I want to move the horizontal edge of the sloping plane along it's normal, keeping the 30 degree slope intact, but I need it to snap to the X or Y world co-ordinate of the vertical wall.

What actually happens is it snaps so the z-axis of the edge normal aligns to the vertical wall. [image: pic here]

I'm trying to align it with the red dots, but it aligns with the blue. Is there a way to do this?

cheers

Comment: Knife project the other plane onto the angled plane from the top.

Comment: ...and if some other time, the planes are in the same mesh, you might want to check out your built-in [TinyCAD](http://zeffii.github.io/mesh_tiny_cad/) add on.

Comment: I think that if you move the cursor closer to the red point on the horizontal plane you will get the snap you want.